# UIViewController subviews release?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
[viewController.view addSubview:view1];
[view1 release];
```

if I want release viewController;

```
[viewController release];
```

do I need manual release view1 before release viewController?

```
UIView *view = (UIView *)[[viewController.view subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
[view release];
[viewController release];
```

should I do this? or just release viewController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you dont have to do that. Just release `viewController` and it will release all of its `subviews` internally. Rest will be taken care by framework.

If you are not using ARC, your code will look like this,

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
[viewController.view addSubview:view1];
[view1 release];

[viewController release];
```

Since you have allocated both `viewController` and `view1` once, you have to release it once as shown above. You dont have to do a release again since you are not doing any `retain` on this after that.

If you do this,

```
UIView *view = (UIView *)[[viewController.view subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
[view release];
```

It will mostly result in a crash when `viewController` is released since you are releasing it twice and `viewController's` subviews are also getting released internally.

Here once thing you have to note is that, `addSubview` retains `view1` as mentioned in [Apple documentation.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html)

> The view to be added. This view is retained by the receiver.
>   After being added, this view appears on top of any other subviews.

This will be released once `viewController` is released and you dont have to manually release it since you dont own it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct way.

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
[viewController.view addSubview:view1];
[view1 release];
[viewController release];
```

When you add a view as subview it'll be retained by the viewcontroller.
addSubview:

Adds a view to the end of the receiver’s list of subviews.

> `- (void)addSubview:(UIView *)view`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> **view**
>
> ```
> The view to be added. This view is retained by the receiver. After being added, this view appears on top of any other subviews.
> ```
>
> **Discussion**
>
> This method retains view and sets its next responder to the receiver,
>   which is its new superview.
>
> Views can have only one superview. If view already has a superview and
>   that view is not the receiver, this method removes the previous
>   superview before making the receiver its new superview.

Reference [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html)

> Important: A view controller is the sole owner of its view and any
>   subviews it creates. It is responsible for creating those views and
>   for relinquishing ownership of them at the appropriate times such as
>   when the view controller itself is released

Reference : [UIViewController Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
UIView *view = (UIView *)[[viewController.view subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
[view release];
```

It'll surely crash when you call release on viewController.

Comment: how are you going to release the view controller when its view is still displayed?